# Responsive css not working on Mobile. i have added meta tag for viewport. but it's working on browser.

Tags: html, css

I am working on old site to make it responsive. and i have added meta tag for viewport in  and one css file for responsive css. but its not working on mobile devices . it's working fine on desktop browser when screen resize below 480px.
here is link http://mojovillage.com/dev4/

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the "initial scale" of the mobile device.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

more information about [using viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: yes i have set 'initial scale' but still not working

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />  and my css file http://mojovillage.com/dev4/oc-content/themes/mojo/css/responsive.css    . its old site i am just trying to make it responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You've given all your `<div>`s `width` in pixels (`px`). It should be `max-width`. All the `<div>`s in your web app have `width` defined replace all of them with `max-width`.

**TLDR**

Use **`max-width`** in place of `width` on all places where you've a container. For Ex: `#header`, `#greenBg`, etc...

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes it's old site with all widths set in pixels. so i have added new css file for mobile http://mojovillage.com/dev4/oc-content/themes/mojo/css/responsive.css  . it works when you resize browser to 480px. but not on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

For starters add media query in your CSS something like:

```
@media screen and (max-width : 480px){
  .col, #sidebar{
  display:block !important;
  float:none !important;
  width:100% !important;

}
```

That will make the columns responsive for devices less than 480px

Example:

[image]

Similarly code for different sizes for all elements in  your CSS or use a responsive CSS framework to make it faster

Comment: Oops! dont mind the color, I was using a dark theme extension

Comment: yes i have added responsive css http://mojovillage.com/dev4/oc-content/themes/mojo/css/responsive.css   . its old site with fixed div sizes i just making it responsive with one extra css. it works on browser but not on mobile device. http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmojovillage.com%2Fdev4%2F

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, My mistake 
added media query in wrong way 
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)

fixed it now.

Thanks for your response!!